# How to get application path

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-2.0

i am using

`string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;`   to get my application path ,but this gives something like

```
C:\Projects\XYZ\ABC\bin\Debug
```

i don't want  bin\Debug .Is there any way to achieve this ?

Comment: Do you want the location of your project files or the location of the running executable?

Comment: PLease describe the rule to obtain expected result

Comment: Shot in the dark - @George, are you perhaps trying to access configuration files or other resources in your project directory from a program running under Visual Studio?  If so, you can set them to copy to the build directory, and your references will work correctly.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The [AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.basedirectory.aspx) property gets the base directory that the assembly resolver uses to probe for assemblies.

So it's functioning 100% as it should. If you were to build your application, cut and paste it somewhere else in another folder or drive. Those changes would be reflected in this property.

Also, you mentioned that you do not want this part `bin\Debug`, so you want what's before that? Please be specific.

Comment: Yes i want everything before bin\Debug

Comment: @George: You realize this will be something hard coded and not flexible at all, right? It's OK if this is exactly what you want, but perhaps you should edit your question and explain in detail what you want the end result to be. What's the target?

Answer (score 16):

to get what you want:

```cs
var enviroment = System.Environment.CurrentDirectory;
string projectDirectory = Directory.GetParent(enviroment).Parent.FullName;
```

Comment: This is the best answer to the question. Congrats, Fredy

Comment: Bulls eye. Gives you the exact folder path of your project rather than bin/debug.
Thanks Fredy

Answer (score 2):

If you want to figure out your application executable path (as I understood):

```
string path = Application.ExecutablePath;
```

Comment: If you want the application path, it's better to use  Application.StartupPath : is the same, but without the exeName

Answer (score 2):

```
string LPath;
string Location = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Reports\\rptEmployInfoStat.rpt";
int index;
index = Location.IndexOf("bin");
if (index > 0)
{
     LPath = Location.Remove(index, 10);
}
else
{
     LPath = Location;
}
rd.Load(@LPath);
```

Answer (score 2):

To be honest, this is not the best pratice but this will give what you want:

```
string dir = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory().Replace("\\bin\\Debug", "");
```

Comment: This won't work well if the application runs on IIS for example, it will give IIS's directory

Answer (score 1):

You are running the program within IDE, and that's the reason why you get this kind of path. Try to build the app and run it outside IDE - you'll see that the method works correctly.

Edit: what you obtain is because IDE runs debug build of your app which is located in $PROJECT_DIR\bin\Debug.

Comment: It has nothing to do with whether you're running in the debugger. It's the location of the EXE. Debug builds go in `<project_path>\bin\Debug` by default, release builds go in `<project_path>\bin\Release` by default. The debugger is irrelevant -- it's strictly a property of your build settings.

Comment: @Joe: you just opened my mind and brought me wisdom of ages. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I am using this:

```
String appSettingsPath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();

        if (!File.Exists(Path.Combine(appSettingsPath, "appsettings.json")))
            appSettingsPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Path.GetDirectoryName(appSettingsPath));
```