# Path to resource files in a VS2010 project

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, .net-4.0

I'm using VS 2010 and .NET 4.0.

I've created a solution, with a single *console* C# project. I've added a few folders in the project via context menu on project > Add > New folder. Then I put some files in there.

I now wish to get the path (or file handle) to one of those resources. Is there a nice way to getting its path?

NOTE 1: The project is on a source control, so I need a way that will work on different file paths.

NOTE 2: If possible, I don't want to use `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` nor `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location`.

EDIT:

It seems, I'd like the direct answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5606776/540352) Stackoverflow question. I want the project directory, without the "bin\Debug"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa457089.aspx):

```
string path = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName( 
  System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase );
```

Also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5606776/540352) Stackoverflow answer.

Comment: I suppose the answer to "Is there a nice way to getting its path?" is _no_, then... 
Do you know, if there's a way to get the project folder path without the "bin\Debug" stuff?

Comment: The bin\Debug folder is in fact the location of your executable. Instead of getting the path without bin\Debug, you should set the property "Copy to output" to "Always" or "If newer" on those files your application needs.