# AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory returns different values in Rider and VS Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, rider

I have a project where I use System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory as part of the path to a json file I need to load. 
The value of the property in Rider is

```
...\MyProject\MyProject.Tests\bin
```

However in VS Studio 2015 the value is

```
...\MyProject\MyProject.Tests\bin\Debug
```

In both cases the name of the run configuration is Debug so I would have expected the return value to be the same.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5606776/2096011%20this%20answer) the property returns the base directory that the assembly resolver uses to probe for assemblies. Is it possible to change that base directory in Rider? Or is there a better method to load the json file that will get around this problem?

I am running Rider version 2017.1.1 on Windows 10.

If I run the code in a console project it works perfect, but if the project type is a library class project or a NUnit Test Project System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory references `\MyProject\MyProject.Tests\bin` instead of `\MyProject\MyProject.Tests\bin\Debug`

Answer (score 1):

Could add additional info about your OS and project type. I check your code on simple console application in Rider. It worked correctly.
[image: screen]

Comment: I updated the question with the additional information