# Application.StartupPath points to C:program files x86/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/Common 7/IDE folder

Tags: c#, winforms, class, ms-access, oledbconnection

I'm developing a WinForms application in C# and I want to connect my access database to my application through the code in the class below, but the application.StartupPath does not point to the bin/debug folder which contains my application's executable instead it points to this C:program files x86/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/Common 7/IDE folder, my application files are not even in the C drive I don't know what is causing the problem.

here is my code:

```
enter code here
    using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace GradeApplicationForm.Models
{
    public static class Connector
    {
        public static OleDbConnection Connect()
        {
            return new OleDbConnection($@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + Application.StartupPath + @"grades.accdb");
        }
    }
}



using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Data;
using Dapper;
using GradeApplicationForm.Models;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace GradeApplicationForm.DataAccess
{
    class StudentDataAccess
    {
            public List<StudentsModel> getStudents()
            {
                

                using (OleDbConnection connection = Connector.Connect())
                {
                string sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_StudentInfo";
                var result = connection.Query<StudentsModel>(sql).ToList();
                return result;

                }
            }
        public bool InsertStudent(string Name, string Age,string Phone,string City,string Department,string UserId)
        {
            bool value;
            using (OleDbConnection connection = Connector.Connect())
            {
                connection.Open();
                List<StudentsModel> students = new List<StudentsModel>();
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Name) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(Age)||string.IsNullOrEmpty(Phone)|| string.IsNullOrEmpty(City))
                {
                    value = false;
                }
                else
                {

                    students.Add(new StudentsModel { Name = Name, Age= int.Parse(Age) ,Phone=Phone,City=City,Department=Department,UserId=int.Parse(UserId)});
                    connection.Execute("INSERT INTO [tbl_StudentInfo](Name,Age,Phone,City,Department,UserId) values(@Name,@Age,@Phone,@City,@Department,@UserId)", students);
                    value = true;


                }
                return value;
            }
        }
        public bool DeleteStudent(int ID)
        {
            bool value;
            using (OleDbConnection connection = Connector.Connect())
            {
                connection.Open();
                List<StudentsModel> students = new List<StudentsModel>();
                if (ID==0)
                {
                    value = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    students.Add(new StudentsModel { ID=ID});
                    connection.Execute("Delete From [tbl_StudentInfo] WHERE ID=@ID", students);
                    value = true;


                }
                return value;
            }
        }
  
    }
}
```

and the error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/55ZSo.png)

Comment: Anything in this thread helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5606747/how-to-get-application-path

Comment: I've already tried that and didn't fix my problem

Comment: Tried which? There are a variety of answers in that thread.

Comment: Normally, you would save the path to your DB in the app settings, rather than use the startup path.  That way it doesn't matter where the accdb file is located

Comment: I tried all the answers in that thread, non of them work in the Connection class, but they all work as expected in the Form classes, it's very confusing

Comment: but I want the relative path of the database file, because if I setup my app in another computer the folder is not gonna be found, would it?

Comment: @AliMohammed Have you Saved / Built your application ? if so, do you see an EXE File in the place where you claim your project is in, or in \Common7\IDE\ ?

Comment: @AliMohammed, open from the Menu bar [Project Properties -> Compile -> Build output path], what is written there ?