# How to find file path after installation of a C# program?

Tags: c#

I have a problem with finding the file after my program installation on another computer. I'm using C# and this is a part of my code:

```
// template path
string tmpPath = @"|DataDirectory|\Templete.docx";

// output path
string outputName = @"|DataDirectory|\Output.pdf";

// shadow file name
string shadowFile = @"|DataDirectory|\temp.docx";

// Create shadow File
File.Copy(tmpPath, shadowFile, true);

// open word
word.Application app = new word.Application();
Document doc = app.Documents.Open(shadowFile);
```

I use`"|DataDirectory|"`, it worked for finding the database but here I use it again to find my word file and it throws me this error:

> System.ArgumentException: 'Illegal characters in path.'

Comment: Also you should not use the program directory to store data. There are per user specific folders for this use.

Comment: [Where is |DataDirectory| defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12276625)

Comment: @JohnnyMopp so what will help me to find the file I want after installation

Comment: @JohnnyMopp i used it in the connection string to find the database, and I thought it will work with this too

Comment: @JAlex what should I use to find the file after installation

Comment: @JohnnyMopp is used it here  ''' private const string constr = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\HuskyCenter.mdf;Integrated Security=True";'''

Comment: I don't think you want to use `|DataDirectory|` here. Is `Templete.docx` installed with your program? Is it a resource? If it is in the exe's folder see: [How to get application path](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5606747) And, as mentioned in the first comment, you should be copying the file to one of the special folders like appdata or temp.

Comment: If this is a windows Forms application, using `Application.ExecutablePath` will tell you where the exe is located. @JAlex's comment has merit - don't store user data along with the application, but if this is a template word file that is part of the application then it makes sense to store next to the exe

Comment: You can make use of this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.specialfolder?view=net-5.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a new variable for DataDirectory.

```
string datadirectory = "c:\pathtodatadirectory";

string tmpPath = datadirectory + @"\Templete.docx";
// output path
string outputName = datadirectory + @"\Output.pdf";
// shadow file name
string shadowFile = datadirectory + @"\temp.docx";
```

You obviously want your data directory to be dynamic. Fetch the directory path from the OS variable.

See this post. [How can I get the current user directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140383/how-can-i-get-the-current-user-directory)

Comment: I would prefer to use `System.IO.Path.Combine()` in order to take care of any formatting issues with directory separation characters.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using reflection with `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location` to get the path of the starting executable. You can use also `Path` to combine paths and filenames, create temporary files, and do other common path operations. Finally, use `Environment.GetFolderPath()` to find where My Documents is, or where `C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local` is and all other special named folders.

```
using static System.IO.Path;
using static System.Environment;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var path = GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
            var template = Combine(path, "Template.docx");
            var tempFile = Combine(GetTempPath(), "temp.docx");
            var userFile = Combine(GetFolderPath(SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "UserPreferences.docx");
            var docFile = Combine(GetFolderPath(SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "MyDocument.docx");
        }
    }
}
```

And alternative to this, is to store the program path in the registry during installation and then read the registry when the program runs

For example write a value to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Application1` or whatever the name is, and read it with `Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software\Application1")`

Comment: running console apps in task scheduler or sql server agent resulted in a wrong path using Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location. I ended up having use this to get the correct executable path: Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase).Replace("file:\\", "");

Comment: `GetExecutingAssembly()` is the way to go then. The rest is is just file path manipulations.